# PIC18F4550 microcontroller pin pulled high on PC wakeup

Tags: usb, pic

I got a PIC18F4550 microcontroller connected to the PC via USB. All is working fine except for one thing. If the PC wakes up from sleep, I notice that certain pins are pulled high (LEDs connected to them light up). I'm pretty sure there's nothing in the MCU code that sets those pins high when the MCU is powered on or something. By the way, if I remove the USB cable and put it back, those pins are not pulled high. Is there any explanation for the PC wakeup mystery? Thanks a lot.
Here is the schematic I'm using:
[image]

Comment: what about the opposite: ground getting pulled low? We have no idea how you power what, whether you have multiple power supplies involved here, how your LEDs are connected. Without at least a partial schematic and much more detailed description, this can all lead to crazy speculaiton.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your concern. All right, I've posted the schematic above. The PIC is getting the power from the USB connection. The LEDs are connected to resistors that are connected to the MCU pins. It seems that certain pins are having this issue because when I connected the LED to a different pin, it didn't light up upon the PC wakeup.

Comment: it could easily be caused by your code ... how are you determining the time delay between wakeup and LED lighting?